# Watir Webdriver script generation

Tags: ruby, testing, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm currently working on writing a suite of test scripts using watir webdriver. Is there something out there that would make script generation easier than looking directly at the HTTP and manually putting the script together? Maybe something captures user interactions with the browser elements and then writes that to a script.

I could just write them manually, but I may as well ask and see if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple record and playback tools that are available for Selenium (like IDE), and several non-open source solutions as well. Most of the Selenium and Watir development communities actively discourage their usage for writing test suites as they create very brittle tests that are difficult to maintain over time.

Watir does allow you to locate elements based on text or regular expressions, which can make it easier to find many elements without looking at the html. In general, though, you the tester have a better idea of the structure of your website, what id elements are there, and what css elements are unique on a page, or unlikely to change with future site updates, etc.

Comment: If writing a set of test scripts isn't a good approach due to maintainability, what would be?

Comment: I said that using record and playback tools to generate tests is discouraged. Manually investigating the html to determine element locators for use in your automated tests is the best practice.